# Project build shows error "Apple Mach-O Linker Error"

Tags: ios, swift

This error shows up when I try to build my project.

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/goradiad/Documents/mpIosAppSwift/matchpointGPS/Pods/GoogleIPhoneUtilities/Frameworks'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/goradiad/Documents/mpIosAppSwift/matchpointGPS/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks'
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/goradiad/Documents/mpIosAppSwift/matchpointGPS/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks'
>
> ld: library not found for -lGGLCloudMessaging
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have no idea where to look. I can see there are many questions related to this but all has different answers.

Comment: Are you using SDK or cocoa pods?

Comment: reinstall cocoapods and try again

Comment: show the full stack trace

Comment: @agent_stack I am using cocoa pods

Comment: Like already suggested, show the full stack trace (even better learn how to read them, that's one thing most of these have in common).

Comment: @Shakil Abbas which pods are you used?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya v1.2.0

Comment: @ShakilAbbas  give me all pod name?

Comment: @ShakilAbbas one important question : currently which file you using .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace?? if you using .xcodeproj then close it and always use .xcworkspace.

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya I'm using .xcworkspace

Comment: @ShakilAbbas  set other linker flag to "$(inherited)"

Answer (score 0):

try deleting derived data and try to install pods if you are using cocoa pods

Answer (score 0):

Please consider **cleaning your project** also **Uninstall App from your simulator**, 
again **run it from XCode** (Key- cmd+R).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cocoapods,

- uncomment `Use frameworks`
- check your target version on xcode
- do pod update
- clean and run.

sometimes Cleaning simulator also works !

Answer (score 0):

I got to resolve that specific linker error by removing -ObjC from
Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags

But I introduced a new error
"No such file or directory: GoogleToolboxForMac"
I assume I've mistakenly deleted GoogleToolboxForMac from Linker Flags and not able to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working by removing All the libraries from
Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags

Better to take a backup of your project before making this changes.